# Splitting pattern into multiple tables with gmatch

Tags: lua, string-matching

I am trying to gsplit my text into multiple tables using a pattern.

So this is my input.

`\x10Hello\x0AWorld`

This is what I expect in my output, 
`\x0A` <- similar inputs will always be 4 chars long

`{{'\x10', 'Hello'}, {'\x0A', 'World'}}`

This is what I have tried so far.

```
local function splitIntoTable(input)
    local output = {}
    for code, text in (input):gmatch('(\\x%x+)(.*)') do
        print(code .. ' ' .. text);
        table.insert(output, { code, text })
    end
    return output
end
```

I made 2 regex groups in `gmatch` the first group is for the hex and the second group is for the text, I am not sure why this isn't working. The `print` statement never gets executed so the loop is never being used.

Comment: Do you have a literal slash in your input, or do you have the ASCII character that results from the escape sequence `\x10`?

Comment: I have ASCII Char that results the escape sequence @cyclaminist

Comment: `local text = "\x10Hello\x0AWorld"` this is what my input would look like, `\x10` is being escaped. its not a literal slash

Comment: Thanks, added an answer based on that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern `'\\x%x+'` matches a literal backslash, an x, and a sequence of hex digits. It does not match the ASCII character generated by a hexadecimal escape such as `'\x0A'`.

You need to replace it with a character class in square brackets such as `'[\x10\x0A]'`. You will have to fill in the character class with whatever ASCII characters (or other bytes) you are expecting in that position in the match.

Unfortunately, this pattern will only match once in a string like `'\x10Hello\x0AWorld'`. The second part of the pattern also needs to be modified.

```
local function splitIntoTable(input)
    local output = {}
    for code, text in (input):gmatch('([\x10\x0A])(.*)') do
        print(code .. ' ' .. text);
        table.insert(output, { code, text })
    end
    return output
end
```

Comment: Uh, Can it not match everything?

Comment: Have you tested the output? It's printing Hello World for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, my solution was only for the first part of the pattern. To fix the second part I need more information.

Comment: Okay but its printing `Hello World` I would like the output to be a 2D table. So multiple tables in a tag each table will contain the text and the code. so the table structure would look like this `{{'\x10', 'Hello'}, {'\x0A', 'World'}}` so the brackets stand for table.

Comment: The second part of the array can be anything. I don't have control over that.

Comment: If the second part of the pattern never contains the characters `'\x10'` and `'\x0A'`, you can change the entire pattern to `'([\x10\x0A])([^\x10\x0A]*)'`.

Comment: Okay nvm, I had to put `([\x10\x0A])([^\x10\x0A]*)` instead of the last. But is there a better way to do this rather then defining the escapes? Because this is really redundant and prob not the best practice

Comment: You could compose the pattern by doing `local start_bytes = '\x10\x0a' local pattern = '([' .. start_bytes .. '])([^' .. start_bytes .. '*])'`, but there's no way to do this internally in the pattern.